# Parseerror using JQM and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using `AJAX` to save data in a `jquery mobile`project. I´m using the below code and the data gets saved, but for some reason I do get `parseerror` in concole and `Error #2` alert is thrown. However the other one , `alert(data['error']);` just print out some actual jquery code?

```
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var formData = $("#event_form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "include/handler/create.ajax.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data['error']){
                        alert('Error #1');
                        alert(data['error']);
                    }else{
                        alert('Success');
                        alert(data['success']);
                        $('#event_form').trigger("reset");
                    }
                },
                error: function(data, errorThrown){
                    alert('Error #2');
                    alert(data['error']);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
```

In the AJAX handler I return message by:

```
$msg = array("error"=>"Technical error");
echo json_encode($msg);
die;
```

Comment: You aren't returning valid JSON. Sounds like your printing out something before your `echo json_encode($msg)`. Take a look at your raw response in your network tab and see what's actually being returned from the request.

Comment: In Chorme => Inspectior  => Network => Response tab is judt say "This request has no response data available"

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php , http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: @Andreas - then that should answer your question. Check your server-side code. There's obviously something wrong with it.